# Getting the Windows command prompt to report an access violation

Tags: windows, terminal, segmentation-fault

In Linux if I run an app from the terminal and there's a seg fault then I see an error message. But in Windows if I run a (command line) app in the command prompt and there's an access violation I get no error. The only way I can see if there was a crash is to open Event Viewer and I can see the error there.

Specifically I am compiling C++ code with g++. Something like:

```
g++ -o foo.exe foo.cpp
foo
```

If `foo.exe` crashes there is no error message. I just get back the `C:\whatever>` prompt with no indication there was a crash. Is there any way to get Windows to display an error in the way that the Linux terminal does?

I vaguely remember in older versions of Windows it would display a message box in the middle of the screen whenever any app caused a GPF, but I think MS removed this many versions ago. If it can be re-enabled then getting the message box would be better than nothing, but having an error reported in the command prompt would be best.

Answer (score 0):

try deleting or renaming these files

> C:\Windows\System32\WeFault.exe
> C:\Windows\System32\WeFaultSecure.exe
> C:\Windows\System32\Wermgr.exe
> and
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WeFault.exe
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WeFaultSecure.exe
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wermgr.exe

After deleting it, you will see the real error handling message from "csrss.exe" process
such as Illegal Instruction, Breakpoint Reached and more!
It also won't show the dialog that the program stopped responding.

But if you're having problems deleting the file, try removing/changing the permissions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).